# Installshield after successful install, does not launch exe

Tags: installshield, exe, launch

I am using a single MSI project.

After a successful install, I select the checkbox to launch my software, and I click finish.

It does not launch my software, even though I checked it and clicked finished.

The only thing I found so far towards ensuring the launch directory was valid, was the property tab for the Checkbox for the "Launch Product". Its property is set as "LAUNCHPROGRAM". Do I have to provide the exe source path for it to launch? I do not see anything related to it. I would imagine that it is simply not launching because it doesn't know what to launch.

Any ideas?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Assign a property in the Property Table refering to the executable. Then Pass this propety name for Launch action to excute.

Hope this might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For more details on this, check out this SO question:

[Run solution exe after installtion using installshield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698145/run-solution-exe-after-installation-using-installshield/36634985#36634985)

Check my answer for addressing some additional issues that may arise.  (Such as ensuring the working directory is set when your program is launched).