# AutoLaunch app after setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, installshield

I have created a setup program using InstallShield which is shipped for free with VS2013.

I have been trying to find a way to optionally launch my application after setup has completed.

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run solution exe after installation using installshield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698145/run-solution-exe-after-installation-using-installshield)

Comment: darn it. This is not for the free version :(