# Run application after silent install using command line in Installshield

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installshield

I created a setup.exe for my project using Install-shield Limited for visual studio 2015.
I was able to run it silently with this command line:

```
Setup.exe /s /v/qb
```

It works fine. Now I want to run the installed application after completing the installation. How can I do it?

(I prefer to add something to the above command-line to do this).

EDIT:
There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698145) like mine. That question wants to run application after installation too. but my question is to run after silent installation (using command-line) and the other question is to run after a normal installation by user. I tried the answers of that question before and they don't work in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run solution exe after installation using installshield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698145/run-solution-exe-after-installation-using-installshield)

Comment: @MegaTron No. it's not. I want to run installed app after silent installation (using command-line). The question you mentioned is about installing by user not by command-line.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the installation project to enable this, or to do it at the command prompt? If the latter, the tags are all wrong, and something like `setup.exe /s /v/qb & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Product\program.exe"` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Michael-Urman I found the answer:

I should use the batch command executing. You can execute more than one command by using `&` symbol (or `&&`).

But I need to run setup first completely then run the program. So I used `start /wait` command.

The final command was this:

```
start /wait setup.exe /w /s /v/qb && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Product\program.exe"
```

`/wait` suspends `cmd` until setup finishes then runs next command.

`/w` keeps `setup.exe` alive until `msi` package installs successfully.

`/s` installs the program silently and `/v` passes arguments to `msi` installer (see [documentation](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm)).

`/qb` shows basic UI of msi installer. (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx)).

`&&` (in comparison with `&`) runs 2nd command if 1st command runs successfully.