# Pre-install exe file before InstallShield main process

Tags: installshield

I am using InstallShield for creating .ism files of C# projects.

To run my project (A) successfully I need to have already installed another program (B) via an .exe file.

Is it possible to add this installation (B) as an extra step on the main installation (A) using InstallShield?

How can I achieve pre-installation using InstallShield for project (B)?

To be honest, I have searched a lot, but could not find something clear.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you heard of [Installshield Suite Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49212599/129130)? (see picture). Run various installer types in sequence. What edition of Installshield do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add it in the end as a step.

.exe for project B can be added on the project A as a file and select to launch it at the end of the installation.

Answer found here: [Run solution exe after installtion using installshield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698145/run-solution-exe-after-installtion-using-installshield) , on @Christopher Painter answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the installation of (B) with a redistributable of (A).

Create an .exe setup for A using installshield, the setup should be bare minimum.

Create a new redistributable of A (tools | prerequisite editor)

Select the setup package as a redistributable in the project B (using installshield | application data | redistributables), you should see it in the list.

Make sure under 'conditional installation', that the 'install before feature selection' is checked.

(optional) right-click on the redistributable package A, select prerequisite order, and then make sure it is set to be the first.

This should execute A prior to B, when executing B.
Note: advisable to include A (if small enough) bundled together with B. So that customer has both of them together in one package (B).