# InstallShield with visual studio 2012 - application does not launch automatically at end of install

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010, installshield-2011, installshield-2012

If after installation I go to Start>Programs>my program>my program.exe then the program is running and i see it in the middle of the screen.

But after installation is finished if I check the checkbox to launch the program then I see my program icon on the bottom in the taskbar and only if I click on the icon in the taskbar the program menu displays in the middle of the screen.

How do I change it so that when the installation is finished and I select to launch the program it will open, and not show only the icon in the taskbar?

Comment: Did you mention the executable file that you want to be launched in the dialog screen?

Comment: Here is a possible solution from another SO question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402882/installshield-after-successful-install-does-not-launch-exe

Answer (score 0):

Open (3) Configure the Target System/Shortcuts/Folders, select the shortcut in the left side pane then change the Run option as "Maximized Window" from the properties panel.